# Filter out duplicates in ng-repeater but increment value next to the item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a filter which is currently removing duplicates in an ng-repeater that I have. I need to be able to show the value amount that is in the array next to the value.

E.g. If I had an array [ 'houston', 'houston', 'dallas' ]

The values on the page would look like: houston (2), dallas (1)

I thought I had a solution but I am getting angular error because I was returning an array instead of the original items I had. I was basically pushing item into the array as [item, 1] where one is the number of times it has been seen. And I would create an else part of the if statement where I would increment that amount but no go.

Need some ideas of how to get this working.

Here is the filter I created

```
.filter('unique', function() {
  return function(collection, keyname) {
    var output = [], 
        keys = [];

    angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var key = item[keyname];

      if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        keys.push(key);
        output.push(item);
      }
    });
    return output;
  };
});
```

Here is the ng-repeater with my filter on it. (Note I have added {{ value }} where I need the number of items to go)

```
<li ng-repeat="info in search.hits | unique: 'type'">
  <a>{{ info.type }} {{ value }}</a>
</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error? You should indeed be returning an array since that is what you are filtering. Also a demo with some sample data would help.

Comment: I got this: "Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop"

Comment: I don't see how the filter code shown would cause an infinite digest loop to be honest. Suspect that is from something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very simple .

Add a counter like this

```
.filter('unique', function() {
  return function(collection, keyname) {
    var output = [];
    angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var obj = output.filter(function(x) {
        return x[keyname] == item[keyname];
      });
      if (obj.length > 0)
        obj.count += 1;
      else {
        item.count = 1;
        output.push(item);
      }
    });
    return output;
  };
});
```

View:

```
<li ng-repeat="info in search.hits | unique: 'type'">
  <a>{{ info.type }} {{ info.count || 0 }}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: legend man. thanks for this. very simple. don't know why i didn't think of this before.

Comment: And if you don't want to modify the existing objects you could first copy the collection using `angular.copy()` and only modify the copied objects

Comment: you can use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) . some browser doesn't support [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) @luke